# Creating OneNote in a specific OneDrive folder

Tags: onenote, onenote-api

I'm trying to add some OneNote integration into an app using the API. I'd like to create a OneNote file in a specific subfolder of the user's OneDrive account - is this possible?

POST https://www.onenote.com/api/v1.0/me/notes/notebooks creates the new notebook in /Documents with the name you provide in the request body - but I'd like to put it somewhere specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For simplicity, the REST APIs does not allow this type of customization and only creates notebooks under the Documents folder.
Our feedback has found that the vast majority of users do not care about the exact location of the notebook as long as the notebook is easily and quickly discover-able.

Comment: I think this limitation makes create note integration very problematic, as inability of creation onenote in the any other location than default makes this API and integration unusable, as API needed to make proper integration (what can be done via OneNote web interface, should be available to do via API).