# OneNote API: Notebook is created always under notebooks folder in OneDrive

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onedrive, microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-graph-files, microsoft-graph-onenote

I am trying to create OneNote NoteBook using OneNote API. (https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/onenote/notebooks)

I can see that there is no way to specify a folder path. It always creates a new NoteBook under "notebooks" folder in OneDrive. Is this a limitation of the API?

I could find one old thread on this: [Creating OneNote in a specific OneDrive folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38570451/creating-onenote-in-a-specific-onedrive-folder)

Is this limitation still there? Let me know if anyone knows any fix/workaround for this.

Answer (score 0):

Please look at the [Create notebook page of Microsoft Graph documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/onenote-post-notebooks?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)

As you can see your other options are listed, including `POST /sites/{id}/onenote/notebooks` - so other sites are possible.

You could try moving it with the OneDrive-API [Move a DriveItem to a new folder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/api/driveitem_move?view=odsp-graph-online)
I suspect this isn't officially supported by MS and will change the id of the NoteBook (as it reflects the eTag/cTag of the drive item) and access via the OneNote-API. I think we discussed this previously under the stack overflow OneNote-API tag.

Comment: Thanks. 

About your first point, am trying to create onenote notebook in a folder in OneDrive so IMO following endpoints won't help: 
/me/onenote/notebooks
/users/{id | userPrincipalName}/onenote/notebooks
/groups/{id}/onenote/notebooks
/sites/{id}/onenote/notebooks 


About the second point, if ID is going to change then it would be a challenge to map between changed ID and IDs from OneNote and OneDrive APIs. Still this is worth exploring. I will create NoteBook using OneNote API, then move it to a specified folder and then upload sections to it using OneDrive APIs. Will try this.